# WebRTC with peerjs datachannel direction

Tags: webrtc, peerjs

I'm using peerjs local server and open 2 browsers on same computer , I can send data from 1 browser to the second, but can't send from the second to the first.
In debug I can see the connection of the first browser is open and the second is close. I have 2 question:

- If 1 browser calls `this.peer.connect('secondBrowser', {reliable:
  true});` , it created a datachannel that is two ways ?
- should each browser call 'connect' to the other browser in order to
  make a two way data transfer ?

In console at 1st browser the log is :

> Open connection to peer y6wfmyb0bg7jlan5

The 2nd browser is

> PeerJS:  Added ICE candidate for: 76xtuwxoiclxzvq3

Comment: Datachannels are full duplex, we can send/recv data in both directions. 
So creating the DataChannel from one side is sufficient.

Comment: Do you have any Idea why in one browser the connection is open and in the other is closed ?

Comment: Is it triggering on close event ? https://github.com/peers/peerjs/blob/10529b6335f545e35219e231c75196e6c83ea577/dist/peer.js#L96

Comment: No, I've added the log console

Comment: add a log in https://github.com/peers/peerjs/blob/10529b6335f545e35219e231c75196e6c83ea577/dist/peer.js#L66 and check, does the data channel initialised  in both the browsers or not?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the data channel created by peer.js is not two way channel.
So you have to connect from both browser.